# QGIS: Create rectangular grid from point grid

Tags: qgis, point, rectangle

I would like to create a grid of rectangles from this grid of points using QGIS 3.16:

[image]

I want the rectangles to be 8km by 8km in size. My points are 8km apart. I tried using the `Rectangles, ovals, diamonds` tool and at first it seems to work. This is what I get:

[image]

However, when I zoom in on the rectangles, this is what I get for each intersection of the rectangles:

[image]

The small white square is problematic since I want to use my grid on rasters later on.

I also used the `Create grid` tool which does not satisfy me because the points are not the centroids and I would like to have rectangles only where there are points (like on the first image of my question). This is the output of the `Create grid` tool:

[image]

What approach would allow me to obtain the expected result?

Comment: Is the rotation of your grid against the CRS axes known?

Comment: How about creating a polygon grid and removing polygons which do not intersect with 4 points?

Comment: @bugmenot123 No this is not known

Comment: @user30184 I edited my question to show you the output of the `Create grid` tool

Comment: Use the create grid tool (shift the extent in the tool by 1/2 a cell size in each direction), then select by location grid cells that do not have a point in them, delete those cells. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XTqL.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "[Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer)" tool, after "Rectangles, ovals, diamonds" tool.

"Tolerance" value should be bigger than the diagonal distance as in the image, and select the source layer for "Input" and "Reference" layer parameters.

[image]

Result (blue one is snapped layer):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I created a grid with `Create grid` and then used the `Join attributes by field value` tool to get the desired result. I had to indicate the grid of rectangles as input layer and my grid of points as input layer 2. I also checked `Discard records which could not be joined`.

Then using `v.transform`, I made a shift in X of `-2000` and in Y of `2000` so the points become the centroids.

Comment: Good alternative. Did you shift the extent by 1/2 a cell (4km) so the points become the centroids?

Comment: @user2856 Thank you, I edited my answer.